# Join identical variables with different arrays from multiple external js files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have made an offline web application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style><!-- some style here --></style>
<script>
var rqid = location.hash.replace('#','');
var js = Math.ceil(rqid / 100);
var id = rqid - ((js - 1) * 100) - 1;
var tg = document.createElement('script')
tg.src = js + '.js'
tg.type = 'text/javascript'
document.head.appendChild(tg);
window.onload = function load() {
var body='<h1>' + title[id] + '</h1> <article>' + content[id] + '</article>';
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = body;}
</script>
</head>
<body id='body'>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is the simplified `article.html` file, which shows articles stored inside external .js files, each with two variables.

> 1.js contains

```
title = ['title of article1','title of article2',...,'title of article100'];
content = ['content of article1','content of article2',...,'content of article100'];
```

> 2.js contains

```
title = ['title of article101','title of article102',...,'title of article200'];
content = ['content of article101','content of article102',...,'content of article200'];
```

For example, `article.html#1` loads `1.js` into the html, and then shows `article1`, and `article.html#101` loads `2.js` and shows `article101`.

It works fine, but there's a problem with the search engine I have written for this application. The search engine code is quite bulky. Sharing it here will not be possible.

The problem is the identical variables in the .js files, which are overridden one after one.

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<script src="3.js"></script>
```

So, search is done only in `3.js`.

> The question is: Is it possible to dynamically join title/content arrays in those .js files and have a unified title/content variable like the following, so the search can be performed in all articles?

```
title = ['title of article1',...,'title of article200'];
content = ['content of article1',...,'content of article200'];
```

**If it is not possible, simply say *no* but please do not recommend to restructure the stored data.**

I would add that the speed/performance is not a problem, in case it is going to be slow.

Comment: The only way this would be possible is if you modified each of the files to check if the variable already exists. If not, create the array, if it does, concat the new data

Comment: Could you guide how to do it, please?

Comment: What options are you giving us when you say "please do not recommend to restructure the stored data?" What parts specifically are you not open to changing?

Comment: Instead of loading the Scripts with a script tag, load them with say `ajax / fetch`, you could then wrap the data into a function closure.

Comment: Jacob, because it would be my final choice to restructure the data, if there is really no way.

Comment: @Siamak Just posted an answer, let me know if that is what you're looking for

Comment: @mhodges, thanks for you answer. I need time to see if/how I could use it. Shall I modify the .js files, adding `globals.title = globals.title ? globals.title.concat(title) : title;` to each of them?

Comment: @Siamak Yes, and then everywhere you were referencing the global variables `title` and `content`, they need to now reference `globals.title` and `globals.content`. And make sure you declare the `window.globals = {}` **before** you load your 1.js, 2.js, etc.

Comment: @Siamak  `because it would be my final choice to restructure the data, if there is really no way` 
 There is a way,.

Comment: @mhodges, working fine, with minimal modification of the original .js files. That's acceptable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with globals across multiple files, it is always a good idea to use some kind of globals structure, that way it is much more explicit as to the fact that the data is, in fact, global, and it makes it much less likely to cause issues with scope pollution.

In your case, you can create a basic object called "globals", which will have a `title` and `content` property, just like you were with your global variables. In fact, those actually go on the `window` object by default, so it works exactly the same - just instead of saying window.title, you can say globals.title, etc. The only difference being that the variables will never be accessed accidentally by default scoping.

```js
window.globals = {};

// file1
(function () {
  var title = ['title of article1','title of article2','title of article100'];
  var content = ['content of article1','content of article2','content of article100'];
  globals.title = globals.title ? globals.title.concat(title) : title;
  globals.content =  globals.content ? globals.content.concat(content) : content;
})();
// file2
(function () {
  var title = ['title of article101','title of article102','title of article200'];
  var content = ['content of article101','content of article102','content of article200'];
  globals.title = globals.title ? globals.title.concat(title) : title;
  globals.content =  globals.content ? globals.content.concat(content) : content;
})();
// file3
(function () {
  var title = ['title of article201','title of article202','title of article300'];
  var content = ['content of article201','content of article202','content of article300'];
  globals.title = globals.title ? globals.title.concat(title) : title;
  globals.content =  globals.content ? globals.content.concat(content) : content;
})();
// final results

console.log(globals.title);
console.log(globals.content);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of how you could do this without having to restructure your `1.js`, `2.js`..

For the purpose of this example I've created a pretend fetch, that can get `1.js`, & `2.js`, if you have any real URL's to test, we should be able to replace the fetch mock with a real one.

```js
const pretenddata = {
  "1.js":
  `title = ['title of article1','title of article2','title of article100'];
content = ['content of article1','content of article2','content of article100']`,
  "2.js": `title = ['title of article101','title of article102','title of article200'];
content = ['content of article101','content of article102','content of article200'];`
};

//lets create a pretend fetch..
function fetch(url) {
  function astext() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(pretenddata[url]);
    });
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({text: astext});
  });
}

async function test() {
  var combined_title = [];
  var combined_content = [];
  async function getData(url) {
    const r = await(await fetch(url)).text();
    var d = new Function(`${r}; return [title, content]`)(); 
    combined_title = combined_title.concat(d[0]);
    combined_content = combined_content.concat(d[1]);
  }
  await Promise.all([
    getData("1.js"),
    getData("2.js")
  ]);
  console.log(combined_title);
  console.log(combined_content);
}

test();
```

Comment: Some changes maybe: `await fetch(url)` should be `await fetch(url).then(response=>response.text())` and `await Promise.all([getData("1.js"),getData("2.js")])` to get the files in parallel.

Comment: I thought `new Function()` was just as frowned upon as `eval()`?

Comment: @mhodges  It's fine as long as you understand the risks,.. Seen as the OP controls `1.js`, `2.js`, were good to go..

Comment: @HMR Good point, I'll update with a more suitable mock, and add the Promise.all..

Comment: @mhodges To add, The eval & new Function are evil, I actually find a bit odd anyway.   How many of use use CDN's,.  it's actually no different,.  If you included a CDN that was compromised, it's just as evil as eval, but for some odd reason this doesn't get as much bad press. :)

Comment: @Keith I agree there is a bad double-standard. I personally do not use CDNs *or* eval for the reliability/security issues, but I get your point - most people are not consistent in that regard.

Comment: @mhodges  Yes, I'm the same.  I prefer to have total control of all resources on my server, so don't use CDN's either.. :)  But I certainly use `new Function`, it's very useful, especially for optimizations, and I see no security issue with it here.  For example template engines etc, it would be bonkers not to use `new Function`.

Comment: There is a security feature that would protect you from loading compromised CDN resources. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity). If you see [this page](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react) has a dropdown next to copy that gives you "copy script tag with SRI"

Comment: @MHR it's still of course not 100%, as if say the CDN was hacked, the attacker would of course change the SRI.  And if you happen to grab this SRI at this point your done for.  But it certainly make's is less likely you get a bad egg.  The other problem is our good old friend IE, and older browsers.. :( with no support..